How to create a partition in Postgresql for Year and Month
I'm trying to create a partition in a PostgreSQL table for year and month.  I want to archive data in S3 based on these partitions, using separate folders for each year and month.  However, including the partition key in the primary key seems to be a requirement.  I only need year and month (YYYY-MM format) in the partition key, not the day and time.
I've tried using to_char(datetime, 'YYYY-MM') in the partition key, but it's not working.  I also tried adding a generated column to hold just the year and month data, but that didn't work either.  Can you help me get this working?

What do you mean by "it's not working"? Can you show us what you tried and what resulted? Plus, what's the relationship between a PostgreSQL partition and your desire to have folders in S3?

Use range partitioning.
